# Can I run a Laravel Route on Linux Cron Job/ Crontab?

Tags: php, linux, laravel, cron

I have an API route that updates my Database,

this is the structure of the route that I want to execute via cronjob,

```
 @extends ('layout')

    @section ('content')

        <script>
                /*--------------------------------------*/
                /* Start Get Employees Data and Update */
                /*------------------------------------*/
                getDataFs();

              function getDataFs()
              {
                    var _token = $("input[name='_token']").val();
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'https:/api/', /* API Url of JSON Data from Hosts */
                        type: 'GET',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        xhrFields: {
                            withCredentials: true
                        },
                        success: function(response){  
                            console.log(response);
                            for(i=0; i < response.length; i++)
                            {
                                $.ajax({
                                    url: '/api/update_list',
                                    headers: {
                                        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                                    },
                                    type: 'POST',
                                    dataType: 'json',
                                    data: { 'employee_data': response[i], '_token': _token },
                                    success: function(response){
                                        console.log(response);
                                    }
                                })
                            }   
                        }
                    });
                }   
                /*--------------------------------------*/
                /* End Get Employees Data and Update   */
                /*------------------------------------*/
        </script>
    @endsection
```

Inside my API route I have an ajax request that gets data from another api,

I know it is possible to run php using sh script or a perl script and adding that `.sh` or `.pl` script on the created cronjob,

What I want to know is that is it possible to run a laravel route inside a `shell script/perl script` on linux?

/usr/bin/php myscript.php to /usr/bin/php laravel/route

If So, can you give me a working sample script with path to my laravel route,

Answer (score 1):

After an hour of research, I was able to solve my problem by researching bit by bit,

here's what i did,

For Laravel 5.4 - to be executed in terminal

1. `php artisan make:command CustomCommand --command=command:name`
2. go to `app/Console/Kernel.php`

   locate schedule function 
   and add this inside `$schedule->command('command:name')->daily();`
3. go to `app/Console/Commands/CustomCommand.php`

   add 'User DB;' and set $signature

   protected $signature = 'command:name';

   set $description = 'This will update employees';

   set handle

   public function handle()

   {

   DB::table('users')->where('id','25')->update(['email'=>'sample@gmail.com']);

   $this->info('Successfully Updated Data!');

   }
4. go to terminal

   go to projectdir

   run 'php artisan command:name'
5. crontab -e

   set min, hour, day, year, month php /path/to/project/artisan update:employee

   e.g. * * * * * php /var/html/laravelproject/artisan command:name

Answer (score -1):

You need install php-cli if you have not installed it yet.
Then just run your php script like this

```
* * * * * * php -f /path/to/php/script.php > /somewhere/log/output.txt
```

If you don't need to log

```
* * * * * * php -f /path/to/php/script.php > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Done